# Getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable on api when runing code inside docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, devops

I am getting the following error when I run the code inside docker container

```
backend_1   |   File "/app/app.py", line 12, in sign_in
backend_1   |     return {"username": data['username'], "password":data["password"]}
backend_1   | TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

when I run code using normal python `app.py`, it works as expected.

This is `app.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from icecream import ic

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/backend/signin', methods=['POST'])
def sign_in():
    data = request.json
    ic("*** app @ 53",data)
    return {"username": data['username'], "password":data["password"]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050, debug=True)
```

Below is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "3500:80"
  frontend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./frontend
  backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./backend
```

This is the Dockerfile for backend:

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./requirement.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirement.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "python", "-u", "./app.py" ]
```

When I request through postman, I get the expected response. But when hitting API through angular frontend it gives an error. I also tried adding `content-type: "application/json"` header, but it didn't work. What am I missing here?

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/codingram/docker-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with nginx

I had to change it from

```
location /backend {
    proxy_method POST;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://bend;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

to this:

```
location /backend {
    proxy_pass http://bend;
}
```